# Carousel Gallery

Tags: html, image, carousel, gallery

I am adding pictures to my website, I have 1 large image and 3 small images in a row beneath. I want to be able to click the smaller images and have them appear in the spot where the larger image is. I am looking into a carousel/slider that shows the images in a small row and when you click on it, it will fade it into a larger image. This is a working example :
http://henrichinc.com/project-gallery/marine-fuel-dispenser-installation/

How can I do this? Or if there is a plugin that can be used?

Comment: Regarding [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792285/472495), I'd suggest you undelete it, so that the question author can be helped by it. It looks good to me. Please consider deleting your comment (since it was much more hostile than the comment you were replying to) and politely asking the commenter to expand on their (rather vague) feedback. If you don't get a (useful) reply then consider tolerating the single downvote - if you persist with answers then you will earn far more rep than that which you will lose.

Comment: @halfer I undeleted it, I left it for a couple of hours and the OP never replied to my answer so I figured it was not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Light Slider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) For these.

Comment: Please Green tick my answer. @Max