# Can't restrict the CSS animation on a particular section or div

Tags: html, css, animation

Somehow I can't make this animation restricted to only one particular section of the webpage. I don't want it to displayed on the whole background, just want to keep it fixed into one div.

Here is the html code

```
<div class="sp-container">
<div class="sp-content">
    <div class="sp-globe"></div>
    <h2 class="frame-1">Reliable</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-2">Fast</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-3">Responsive</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-4">Beautiful</h2>
    <h2 class="frame-5">
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
        <span>bla</span>
    </h2>
    <a class="sp-circle-link" > Merry go round</a>
</div>
```

here is the css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow');

body {
    background: #310404 url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wOvQAhzWCrM/maxresdefault.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1.main, p.demos {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
    font-size: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
    -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
    -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
    -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
    animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
    animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
    animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 282px;
    height: 273px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
    background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    -moz-transform: scale(5);
    -o-transform: scale(5);
    -ms-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #3f1616;
    font-size: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
    -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
    -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
    animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
    background: #85373b;
    color: #fff;
}
/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        -moz-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        transform: scale(5);
    }
}
    @keyframes fadeInRotate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

This animation was not created by me. I know it's something silly.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve? It looks like your animation is working as intended.

Comment: I am really sorry. I want to add other content below that animation. Somehow that text is also flashing in the content below it. I want it to be restricted in one container. Thanks

Comment: @AnasM.I Can you tell me if my answer helped or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed to one div. It's fixed to sp-container.

If you are trying to make only one section animated, you can wrap that section in sp-container and remove sp-container from the rest of your content. If sp-container  is used for something other than animation you can remove just the animation elements from sp-container and add them back.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow');

body {
    background: #310404 url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wOvQAhzWCrM/maxresdefault.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1.main, p.demos {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
}
.animation-blur {
     -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
    animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
    font-size: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
    animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
    animation-delay: 14s;
}
.animation-fade {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
    animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
}
.sp-globe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 282px;
    height: 273px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
    background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    -moz-transform: scale(5);
    -o-transform: scale(5);
    -ms-transform: scale(5);
    transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #3f1616;
    font-size: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
    background: #85373b;
    color: #fff;
}
/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        -moz-transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    20%, 75% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        transform: scale(5);
    }
}
    @keyframes fadeInRotate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

This is your code with animation removed from sp-container and added to specific elements if you want animation on specific content you can use either :

```
<div class="animation-fade"></div>
<div class="animation-blur"></div>
```

Also note, you have animation delay on some elements like h2 when its wrapped in sp-container. So if you are not going to use animation with your h2 tags I suggest removing the animation delay.